# Is it valid to target a CSS element with an ID only if it's inside a certain class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

We have a modal and full page view of our application. For the modal, we attach a "modal" class to the body, so that we can select elements based on whether or not they are contained within this "modal" class.

Several of the items we need to target have IDs. Is it bad practice to select these items like so?

```
.modal #child-element-with-id { ... }
```

The above works perfectly fine in all the browsers I've tested, but someone on the code review is complaining about it from a code smell perspective.

I know IDs are supposed to be unique and shouldn't be nested, but doesn't this constitute an exception? To me it seems like the cleanest way to target the ID, instead of coming up with separate IDs for modal and full page views.

Comment: As you mentioned, IDs are supposed to be unique. The modal is still on the same page as the rest of your "full page view." Why not just name the elements inside the modal with a prefix or suffix like `#modal-title-id` vs `#title-id`?

Comment: I see nothing bad on this ... it's perfectly right

Comment: _"I know IDs are supposed to be unique and shouldn't be nested"_ I've never heard the nested part before. I see no reason why you can't either.

Comment: Thanks, to me it wasn't too smelly. Going to push back in the code review.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, yes. However, if you need to reuse this style for multiple elements, you should create a class.

For example if you do:

```
.modal #child-element-with-id { /* same style */ }
.modal #child-element-with-id-2 { /* same style */ }
.modal #child-element-with-id-3 { /* same style */ }
```

Then you should be making a class to avoid style duplication.

**To answer your question, the jury is still out and you'll have to decide if selecting a nested ID works for your use case :)**

The only issue I could see that if you move the ID to a different element, this may cause confusion and be hard to debug, because your CSS expects the ID to be nested in a class.

Answer (score 1):

Styling by ID is generally frowned upon. If you have the opportunity to edit the markup, why not add a class to those elements with IDs?

You may find that once you have introduced a highly specific selector (0, 1, 1, 0) you may end up having to add to it later for something even more specific – this is the scenario we try to avoid.

> …instead of coming up with separate IDs for modal and full page views

I would reconsider this setup and add classes onto the elements with ID's. If you are *already* styling those elements by #id it's quite easy to swap the CSS selector to a class. If you find it's *not* easy to style those `#id`s now that they are classes - my point may already be proven :)

Hope that helps!